# ¿Como pasar una función de Javascript a una plantilla EJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, ejs

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo pasar una función que tengo en un archivo.js en este caso la funcion click(), dentro de otro archivo.ejs para ejecutar esta función en un botón.

Botones en archivo.ejs que quiero ejecutar.

```
<div style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 40px;">
        <a href="/cursos/<%=curso._id%>/enrolled/<%=anterior%>">
              <button type="button" onclick=<%=click% class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><< Anterior Lección</button>
        </a>
        <a href="/cursos/<%=curso._id%>/enrolled/<%=siguiente%>">
              <button type="button" onclick=<%=click%> class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Siguiente Lección >></button>
        </a>
</div>
```

```js
APP.JS
router.get("/cursos/:id/enrolled/:tema/", function(req,res){
 Cursos.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCourse){
  if(err){
   res.redirect("/cursos");
  } else {
   var tema  = req.params.tema;
   var found = foundCourse.content;
   var siguiente;
   var anterior;
   
   function click(){
   found.forEach(function(element){
    for (var i = 0; i < element.index.length; i++){
      if(element.index[i].ref == tema){
       var atras  = i - 1;
       anterior = element.index[atras].ref;

       var next  = i + 1;
       var final = element.index[next].ref;
       siguiente = final;
      }
       
     }
    })
   }
  res.render("cursos/" + tema, {curso: foundCourse, tema: tema, siguiente: siguiente, anterior: anterior, click: "click()"});
  }
 });
});
```